# How do I use Boost Random

Tags: c++, boost, boost-random

I need to generate random number with Boost Random.

I tried to follow the general guide.

I extracted the files of the library. So if I want to use the classes and objectj of the library how I should do?

First I know including the library in the program. Then I have to compile the library and the program.cpp itself? (And both with the same compiler - I'm using g++).

I am using a virtual box of ubuntu. It is first time that I am using library so I really don't know.

Comment: What doesn't work for you in particular? As is your question is _too broad_, we don't write step by step tutorials here. Also note that [Pseudo number Generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) is part of the current standard library already.

Comment: If you have a compiler that supports at least C++11, (which is the vast majority of C++ compilers at this point), you should prefer the Standard's `<random>` header over `<boost/random.hpp>`.

Comment: in the part 6 of the guidehttp://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html there is as an exemple and I could not succeded neithe copying the two main ways to link to libraries that they explain because so far I really know a bit . so I would like to know for genearl library , like could be the one of boots, how to link and use it.

Comment: the random number for my case must be double not just integer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the random number for my case must be double not just integer...

So, you use a real number distribution.

---

I'm not this kind of "getting started" is the best fit for StackOverflow, but I'll give you this quick hints:

In your Ubuntu virtual box:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
mkdir -pv ~/myproject
cd ~/myproject
```

Create a file using your favourite editor. If you have none, `gedit main.cpp` or `nano main.cpp` is a start:

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::random::mt19937 rng;                                        
    boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double> gen(0.0, 1.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << gen(rng) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Now compile it using

```
g++ -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp -o demo
```

The program is now ready to run: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a57fa7a937e259d)</kbd>**

```
./demo
```

Printing

```
0.814724
0.135477
0.905792
0.835009
0.126987
0.968868
0.913376
0.221034
0.632359
0.308167
```

### Seeding && Non-Header Only Libraries

The above works because the Boost Random library is mostly header only. What if you wanted to use the `random_device` implementation to seed the random generator?

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8814727946621586)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::random::random_device seeder;
    boost::random::mt19937 rng(seeder());                                        
    boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double> gen(0.0, 1.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << gen(rng) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Now you'll have to link as well: Compiling with

```
g++ -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp -o demo -lboost_random
```

Now the output will be different each run.

### BONUS: Standard Library instead of Boost

You don't need Boost here at all:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c86f395b45c5c34b)</kbd>**

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::random_device seeder;
    std::mt19937 rng(seeder());                                        
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> gen(0.0, 1.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << gen(rng) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Compile with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp -o demo
```

And run it again with `./demo`

### BONUS

Showing a whole gamut of distributions that have mean=0 and stddev=1:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2d43857b53eed8c)</kbd>**

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/serialization/array_wrapper.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::accumulators;
using Accum = ba::accumulator_set<double, ba::stats<ba::tag::variance, ba::tag::mean> >;
using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

static double identity(double d) { return d; }

template <typename Prng, typename Dist, typename F = double(double), size_t N = (1ull << 22)>
void test(Prng& rng, Dist dist, F f = &identity) {
    Accum accum;

    auto s = Clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i<N; ++i)
        accum(f(dist(rng)));

    std::cout 
        << std::setw(34) << typeid(Dist).name() 
        << ":\t" << ba::mean(accum) 
        << " stddev: " << sqrt(ba::variance(accum)) 
        << " N=" << N 
        << " in " << ((Clock::now()-s)/1.s) << "s"
        << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());                                        

    auto shift = [](double shift) { return [=](double v) { return v + shift; }; };
    auto scale = [](double scale) { return [=](double v) { return v * scale; }; };

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpos;
    test(rng, std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(-sqrt(3), sqrt(3)));
    test(rng, std::weibull_distribution<double>(), shift(-1));
    test(rng, std::exponential_distribution<double>(), shift(-1));
    test(rng, std::normal_distribution<double>());
    test(rng, std::lognormal_distribution<double>(0, log(0.5)), shift(-exp(pow(log(0.5),2)/2)));
    test(rng, std::chi_squared_distribution<double>(0.5), shift(-0.5));
    {
        auto sigma = sqrt(6)/M_PI;
        static constexpr double ec = 0.57721566490153286060;
        test(rng, std::extreme_value_distribution<double>(-sigma*ec, sigma));
    }
    test(rng, std::fisher_f_distribution<double>(48, 8), shift(-(8.0/6.0)));
    test(rng, std::student_t_distribution<double>(4), scale(sqrt(0.5)));
    test(rng, std::student_t_distribution<double>(4), scale(sqrt(0.5)));
}
```

Prints

```
  St25uniform_real_distributionIdE: +0.000375 stddev: +1.000056 N=4194304 in +0.169681s
       St20weibull_distributionIdE: +0.001030 stddev: +1.000518 N=4194304 in +0.385036s
   St24exponential_distributionIdE: -0.000360 stddev: +1.000343 N=4194304 in +0.389443s
        St19normal_distributionIdE: -0.000133 stddev: +1.000330 N=4194304 in +0.390235s
     St22lognormal_distributionIdE: +0.000887 stddev: +1.000372 N=4194304 in +0.521975s
   St24chi_squared_distributionIdE: -0.000092 stddev: +0.999695 N=4194304 in +1.233835s
 St26extreme_value_distributionIdE: -0.000381 stddev: +1.000242 N=4194304 in +0.611973s
      St21fisher_f_distributionIdE: -0.000073 stddev: +1.001588 N=4194304 in +1.326189s
     St22student_t_distributionIdE: +0.000957 stddev: +0.998087 N=4194304 in +1.080468s
     St22student_t_distributionIdE: +0.000677 stddev: +0.998786 N=4194304 in +1.079066s
```

Comment: how I can generate a random number with mean valeu zero and standard deviation one ?

Comment: You use a distribution that satisfies it. Many exist. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random#Random_number_distributions All of these exist in Boost AFAIK (so if you _must_ use Boost, there's little difference)

Comment: Just for fun, added 10 different distributions with those properties: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2d43857b53eed8c). Pick the normal distribution, unless you know what you're doing : )

Comment: `boost::random::mt19937` can be seeded with more than 32 bits of seed material with `boost::random::mt19937 rng(seeder);` (note the lack of parens). That's because `boost::random::random_device` has a `.generate` member function which allows for usage as a SeedSequence.