# How to change the seed in gaussian distribution (boost)

Tags: c++, random, boost, random-seed

I have found this example on  *[How to use boost normal distribution classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078474/how-to-use-boost-normal-distribution-classes)*

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::mt19937 rng; // I don't seed it on purpouse (it's not relevant)

    boost::normal_distribution<> nd(0.0, 1.0);

    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, 
                        boost::normal_distribution<> > var_nor(rng, nd);

    int i = 0; 
    for (; i < 10; ++i) {
        double d = var_nor();
        std::cout << d << std::endl;
    } 
}
```

I was wondering what I have do add to the code to generate a different random numbers each time. I am using the number called produced d in a for loop, but at every time I run the program I always obtain the same numbers. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Why don't you seed the engine before passing it to the constructor of `variate_generator`?

Comment: Hey friend , do you mean here : boost::mt19937 rng; ? I should pass an argument to rng ? It is what I would like to discover..

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way and it seems to work:

I added the library:

```
      #include<time.h>
```

and modifying just this:

```
    boost::mt19937 rng(time(0));
```

in this way I guess that the seed is the time of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You seed the engine. See e.g. This answer which includes many many distributions: [How do I use Boost Random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591592/how-do-i-use-boost-random/48592524#48592524)